# Object detection using cv android

Tags: opencv

I am using Open CV for detection of edge of object. When I am capture image using camera and apply canny edge also morphological operation but it is not give actual edge points of object. How can I get this points?[image]

Comment: please anyone know about this for android give answer asap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using dilation and Gaussian Blur and dilation for edge detection.

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new Size(11, 11), 0);
        // Imgproc.Canny(imgSource, imgSource, 20, 60);

        // 2) AdaptiveThreshold -> classify as either black or white
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imgSource, imgSource, 255,
                Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 2);

        // 3) Invert the image -> so most of the image is black
        Core.bitwise_not(imgSource, imgSource);

        // 4) Dilate -> fill the image using the MORPH_DILATE
        Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE,
                new Size(3, 3), new Point(1, 1));
        Imgproc.dilate(imgSource, imgSource, kernel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another edge detection algorithm or different threshold for edge detect.